# print a label from an add button in java

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

I have a button named " add", this button takes 3 user input (name,id,gpa) and insert them into an array that save all the students records. here is an example:

[image]

my question is, I want to be able to create a label that has all the students inserted records, can I do that and how?

**the add button method:**

```
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = txt2.getText();
            String ID = txt1.getText();
            String GPA = txt3.getText();
            boolean add = addNewStudent(name, ID, GPA);
            SIS.add(result);
            if (add) {

                result.setText("New student added: name = " + name + ", ID = " + ID + " GPA: " + GPA);
            } else result.setText("Cannot add, " + name + " already on file");

      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be somewhat clearer. What is `result` in your code? Why do you add it to the layout every time a new student is inserted? You should add it only once.
The simplest way to "update" the content of the label might be:

```
result.setText(result.getText() + " more text ");
```

A better option could be not to use a label, which is not the perfect widget to display a set of data, but, for example, a table.

As far as I understand you are using Swing. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) you can find how to create a table, add it to the layout and bind it to your data model.

Comment: the result is for displaying the output , check the picture and you see "new student added ...." , and I need to save all the records in one place so I can't just set them as a text instead of adding them